# Adding dynamic block to home page clears everything except that block Lesti cache

Tags: magento, hole-punching

Well i have a block on home page which contains multiple product sliders, I this block to be dynamic so I added this block name to the lesti fpc dynamic blocks. But after adding it except this block every thing gone, nothing in head tag, no header or footer.

Here is my locl.xml

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="home_page_main_block" as="home_page_main_block" cache_lifetime="null" template="page/blocks/home_page_main_block.phtml" before="-"/>
        <block type="core/template" name="home_page_blog_block" as="home_page_blog_block" template="page/blocks/home_blog_block.phtml" after="home_page_main_block"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: Removed the *FreePascal* tag. This is obviously about *FPC = fullpagecache*, not *FPC = FreePascal Compiler*.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks for the correction.